# Proofing Analytic continuation and stationary increments of an exponential Family

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

In U.Küchler "Exponential Families of Stochastic Processes" 1997 Theorem 4.2.1 we have the following setup. 
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_{t})_{t\geq0})$ be a filtered measurable space. Let $P_{\varphi}$ be a probability measure on that space. Let 
$P_{\varphi}^{t}$ be the restrition of $P_{\varphi}$ to $\mathcal{F}_{t}$. 
We assume that for the exponential family $\mathcal{P}=\{P_{\varphi},\varphi\in\Gamma\}$ we have the following representation of Radon-Nikodym-Derivatives for 
arbitrary $\varphi_{0}\in\Gamma$
\begin{align}
\frac{dP_{\varphi}^{t}}{dP_{\varphi_{0}}^{t}}=\exp[<\varphi-\varphi_{0},B_{t}>-\phi_{t}(\varphi)+\phi_{t}(\varphi_{0})]\,\varphi\in\Gamma,t\geq 0
\end{align}
Now Küchler states:

1. If $int \Gamma \not=\emptyset$, the canonical process $B_{t}$ has independent increments under $P_{\varphi},\forall \varphi \in \Gamma$. 
   The Laplace transfrom of the increments $B_{t}-B_{s}$ under $P_{\varphi}$ is for $\lambda \in \Gamma-\varphi$ given by
   \begin{align}
   E_{\varphi_{0}}\left[\exp[<\lambda,B_{t}-B_{s}>]|\mathcal{F}_{s}\right]&=\exp[\phi_{s}(\varphi)-\phi_{s}(\lambda+\varphi)-\phi_{t}(\varphi)+\phi_{t}(\lambda+\varphi)]
   \end{align}
2. In particular, $B_{t}$ has stationary increments if and only if $\phi_{t}(\varphi)$ is of the form $tf(\varphi)$.

$B_{t}$ is a stochastic process, which is right-continuous with limits from the left and $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-adapted. And $\phi_{t}$ is a function which is positive real, non-random and right-continuous with limits from the left.

To point 1: 
We choose $\varphi_{0}\in \Gamma$ arbitrary. With the canonical representation from above, we know from some previous stuff (not mentioned here), that
 $(dP_{\varphi}^{t}/dP_{\varphi_{0}}^{t})_{t\in\mathbb{R}_{+}}$ is a $P_{\varphi_{0}}$-martingale.
So for $s\leq t$:
\begin{align}
E_{\varphi_{0}}\left[\frac{dP_{\varphi}^{t}}{dP_{\varphi_{0}}^{t}}|\mathcal{F}_{s}\right]&=\frac{dP_{\varphi}^{s}}{dP_{\varphi_{0}}^{s}}\\
E_{\varphi_{0}}\left[\exp[<\varphi-\varphi_{0},B_{t}>+\phi_{t}(\varphi_{0})-\phi_{t}(\varphi)]|\mathcal{F}_{s}\right]&=\exp[<\varphi-\varphi_{0},B_{s}>+\phi_{s}(\varphi_{0})-\phi_{s}(\varphi)]\\
\Leftrightarrow E_{\varphi_{0}}\left[\exp[<\varphi-\varphi_{0},B_{t}-B_{s}>]|\mathcal{F}_{s}\right]&=\exp[\phi_{s}(\varphi_{0})-\phi_{s}(\varphi)-\phi_{t}(\varphi_{0})+\phi_{t}(\varphi)]
\end{align}
and therefore $\forall \lambda \in \Gamma-\varphi_{0}$ we get the conditional Laplace-Transform
\begin{align}
E_{\varphi_{0}}\left[\exp[<\lambda,B_{t}-B_{s}>]|\mathcal{F}_{s}\right]&=
\exp[\phi_{s}(\varphi_{0})-\phi_{s}(\lambda+\varphi_{0})-\phi_{t}(\varphi_{0})+\phi_{t}(\lambda+\varphi_{0})]
\end{align}
**Now comes the unclear Part**: Küchler states that the conditional Laplace transform of $B_{t}-B_{s}$ under $P_{\varphi_{0}}$ is equal to a non-random function in the open set $int \Gamma-\varphi_{0}$. By analytic continuation the above stated conditional Laplace transform is non-random in its entire domain. Why we need continuation here? Cause we have already stated, that the formula holds for all $\lambda\in\Gamma-\varphi_{0}$. **I could need a proof here**.

To point 2. **I am actually stuck at the beginning**